# ClickHouse as a storage engine for Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, clickhouse

Without going deep into details a small background:

What I have:

- Around 30TB of compressed data distributed across several servers in ClickHouse database and updated daily.

What I want:

- Work with the data via Spark as a state-of-the-art solution for working with data in  MapReduce paradigm.

As far as I understand [Spark is not a database and cannot store data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34778856/10961405). So it needs a storage
engine. It will be perfect to keep our data in ClickHouse and do without migration to Hive or other storage mentioned [here](https://databricks.com/session/storage-engine-considerations-for-your-apache-spark-applications). I've only found [this](https://github.com/VaBezruchko/spark-clickhouse-connector) small project on GitHub and nothing more in the global web about using ClickHouse a data engine for Apache Spark.

So my question is: has anybody done it yet? Or perhaps it is not a good idea. So why? And what will be a good choice in such scenario?

Comment: Clickhouse has a jdbc driver. You therefore don't need a specific connector

Answer (score 1):

From spark perpective, by using `jdbc` connector, connecting to Clickhouse is similar to how we connect with other databases like postgres, mysql etc.,

Here is a python based sample code. However the same logic applies to Java, Scala etc.,

```py
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, "foo"),
            (2, "bar"),
            (3, "baz"),
        ],
        ["id", "value"]
    )

    df.write.format("jdbc")\
    .option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:9000/default") \
    .option("driver", "com.github.housepower.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver") \
    .option("dbtable", "default.test_table")\
    .option("createTableOptions", "engine=MergeTree() order by id")\
    .option("user", "default") \
    .option("password", "")\
    .mode('overwrite').save()
```

In the above example, we used `clickhouse-jdbc` jar. This need to be there in  SPARK_HOME/jars.

More details on other variants of java libraries for clickhouse is described well in [this github repository](https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-java)

Answer (score 0):

It's definitly a good idea! There is a new [spark-clickhouse-connector](https://github.com/housepower/spark-clickhouse-connector) based on DataSource V2 API and ClickHouse gRPC protocol which makes you write/read data to/from ClickHouse more efficiently. In particular, it can transparently convert your access to Distributed table to Local table.

[Quick Start Demo with Spark SQL](https://housepower.github.io/spark-clickhouse-connector/quick_start/02_play_with_spark_sql/)

[Quick Start Demo with Spark Shell](https://housepower.github.io/spark-clickhouse-connector/quick_start/03_play_with_spark_shell/)

Comment: Please include a demonstration as to [how this tool solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) as part of your answer.

Comment: I can see that you have an affiliation with this library. You are [encouraged to share this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and to _show_ a solution instead of _telling_.

Comment: @tjheslin1 It provides a quick start section in home page includes demos how to use spark sql and spark shell to access clickhouse via this connector. I update the answer adding direct link to the demo.

Comment: Please include a demonstration as to [how this tool solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) as part of your answer.